# 無線LANで繋いでいるスマホからネット経由でWebサイトへアクセスすると、PCからアクセスしたIPアドレスと同じになる？

Tags: php, network

**前提**
・インターネットに無線LANで繋いでいるPCに、スマホも接続
・スマホは、無線LAN経由でしかインターネットに接続しない

---

**質問**
・PCからアクセスした場合も、スマホからアクセスした場合も、同じIPアドレスとなる？
・$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]などで取得するIPアドレス(グローバルIPアドレス？)は、クライアント端末ごとではなく、LAN単位のアドレス？？
・同じLAN内からアクセスされた場合、該当端末をサーバ側から個別に突き止めることは出来ない？

Comment: 前提の「インターネットに無線LANで繋いでいるPCに、スマホも接続」の部分がよく分かりません。スマホはPCと同じクライアントなのか、それともPCとのみホットスポット等でネットワーク接続を共有するのを想定している？

Comment: PCもスマホも、家のWi-Fiルーター経由でネットワーク接続しています。これは同じクライアント端末と認識されるということですか？　「ホットスポット」は使用したことがないのでよく分からないのですが、公衆無線LANへ接続しているわけではありません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スマホもPCもルータ経由でインターネットに接続しているのならば、外部から見えるのはルータのWAN側に設定されたグローバルIPまでで、
クライアントのスマホやPCにはローカルIPが割り振られるので基本的に外部のネットワークからLAN側のIPを知る術は無いのではないでしょうか。